# Combine Rows and Count Values

Tags: python, merge, count, row

I have a dataframe similar to this:

```
OrderNum Product Quantity

1 Gum 2

1 Candy 4

2 Chocolate 8

3 Gum 3

3 Soda 1

4 Chocolate 2

5 Gum 2

5 Soda 2
```

For each product ordered I would like to find out what other products and how many of each were ordered with it, based on the order number's being identical.

I'd like to see something like this:

```
Gum 7 Candy 4 Soda 3

Candy 4 Gum 2

Chocolate 10

etc.
```

Thank you for the help!

Connor

Comment: I'm confused by your expected output.  How did you get Candy 4, Gum 2?  The first and last line make sense to me (it's the sum of the Quantity grouped by the Product).  But the second one doesn't match that pattern.

Comment: On OrderNum 1 candy was ordered 4 times, also on OrderNum1 gum was ordered 2 times. Since candy was not ordered anywhere else, the output for products ordered with candy is candy 4 and gum 2.

Comment: I think I get it now.  There were 3 orders that have Gum.  Of those orders, 7 sets of Gum were ordered in total (across 3 different orders), and 4 things of Candy and 3 things of soda.

Comment: Great! Can you tell me how to do this in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is find the associations between each element.  If two (or more) orders have "Candy", how many of each other Product do they contain.

This is the best I could come up with.  First, group by each Product in order to find all orders that have that Product.  Then, take that subset from the original dataframe, and get the sum of the Quantity of each product.

```
# group by the products
products = df.groupby("Product")

# each groupby element is a tuple
# the first entry is the value (in this case, the Product)
# the second is a dataframe
# iterate through each of these groups
for p in products:
  sub_select = df[df["OrderNum"].isin(p[1]['OrderNum'])]
  quantities = sub_select.groupby("Product").Quantity.sum()

  # print the name of the product that we grouped by
  # and convert the sums to a dictionary for easier reading
  print(p[0], quantities.to_dict())
  # Candy :  {'Candy': 4, 'Gum': 2}
  # Chocolate :  {'Chocolate': 10}
  # Gum :  {'Candy': 4, 'Soda': 3, 'Gum': 7}
  # Soda :  {'Soda': 3, 'Gum': 5}
```

`sub_select` will be a subset of our original dataframe. For example, it will contain all rows for all orders that had Candy.  `quantities` then groups all of those orders together by the Product in order to get the sum of the Quantity for each product across all matching orders.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was perfect and very helpful.

Comment: No problem. If you wouldn't mind accepting this as the answer, that would be much appreciated!